# Can you identify this LED?

Tags: led, identification

I am learning basic electronics by repairing a series of broken devices in my home lab/workshop. My first repair is a very common problem: some defective LEDs on a Style Selections 15-in Adjustable Brushed Steel Casual/Transitional Integrated Desk Lamp with Metal Shade Model # 17794-000 from Evolution Lighting (www.evolutionlightingllc.com). The company doesn't seem to respond to parts requests for components, and my searches on the internet haven't turned up a part number or supplier for a few replacement LED's.

The LED's appear to be 5mm bright white straw hat with a forward voltage of 3.2 volts. I have attached photos in case someone can help me with component identification, manufacturer/supplier and a part number. (This is a simple repair that should keep a useful item out of the landfill - and help me perfect my soldering/desoldering skills.)

Many thanks to anyone who can guide me to a solution.[image: LED side view]

[image: LED top view[![][2]]

Comment: Why yes, its an LED

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It seems to be a 5mm bright white straw hat possibly with a nominal forward voltage of 3.2 volts at a nominal forward current of 20 mA.

What I mean to say this is a bog standard led and you could replace it with any typically 20mA at 3.2V led of various colors as long as it fits. Nothing special about it.

<sub>Also the reviews on that lamp are **garbage**. The lamps routinely fail, with dead leds. Likely a bad design in the regulation or over-driving the leds. Replacing the leds will only prolong the inevitable. At 20 bucks, your better off buying a better lamp.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/334-15-X1C5-1QSA/1080-1008-ND/2675499

http://media.digikey.com/PDF/Data%20Sheets/Everlight%20PDFs/1246342150_6815.pdf

These are pretty good bright LEDs, Neutral white 3.6~7.1 Cd @ 50deg  get a dozen or more. $38/100pc

If anyone wants 30deg >16Cd 4500K white are avail. for $50/200pc

I would not be too concerned about the the stubby lens, it just gives broad light angle ( unknown angle, intensity and colour temp) possibly for a short task light.  50deg is pretty good, maybe 30 is preferred with many LEDs.